# Flash CS6/as3: Using cursor to draw rectangle dynamically in a published swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shapes, drag

I'm having a bit of a problem. I'm creating a swf that will allow someone to draw a rectangle dynamically in a published swf, then they can drag a shape and place it within the rectangle they just drew.

I have the swf working so that you can draw a rectangle, no problem. Where the issue arises is when trying to drag one of the shapes on the screen into the newly-drawn rectangle, it ends up drawing another rectangle while the shape is being dragged.

My question, I guess, is how do I "turn off" the code that allows for a rectangle to be drawn after I've drawn the one I want to use?

This is the code I used for drawing the rectangle (I got this from a tutorial online). The draggable shapes don't show up until the rectangle has been drawn (they are on the next frame):

```
stop();

import flash.display.Shape;

var temporaryDrawing:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(temporaryDrawing);
temporaryDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 1);

var myDrawing:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(myDrawing);
myDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 1);

var mouseHolding:Boolean=false;
var clickedX:Number;
var clickedY:Number;


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

function mDown(MouseEvent):void{
    mouseHolding = true;
    clickedX = mouseX;
    clickedY = mouseY;
}

function mUp(MouseEvent):void{
    mouseHolding = false;
    myDrawing.graphics.drawRect(clickedX, clickedY, mouseX-clickedX, mouseY-clickedY);
    nextFrame();
    clearTemp ()
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mMove);
function mMove(MouseEvent):void{
    if (mouseHolding){
        clearTemp ();
        temporaryDrawing.graphics.drawRect(clickedX, clickedY, mouseX-clickedX, mouseY-clickedY)

    }
}

function clearTemp():void{
    temporaryDrawing.graphics.clear();
    temporaryDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate by the target of the `MouseEvent`.

The draw listener is added to the stage. `currentTarget` will be exactly that, `stage`. The listener that initiates the dragging is (probably) added to the object that should be dragged. `currentTarget` will be a reference to that.

Due to bubbling every `MouseEvent` will end up at the `stage`, that's why your rectangle is drawn again. The difference is that the `target` of the `MouseEvent` will be different.

In the function that handles the `MouseEvent` for drawing the rectangle, simply check if `currentTarget == target`, if that's the case, the mouse was clicked on the `stage` and nothing else. If they are not the same, the mouse was clicked on something else, the intention is not to draw a rectangle.

This will basically disable the rectangle drawing if anything else is clicked that's not the `stage`.

---

You can probably also achieve this with `stopPropagation()` and adding listeners for different event phases. But I have no time to think this through.

Comment: I'm understanding the logic, but I'm a bit lost on how to implement what you've suggested. And apparently I can't use the Return button on my keyboard when responding to your post so I'll make this one long paragraph instead. You said to check if currentTarget == target, but I'm not sure where in my code I would be doing that. As you can probably tell I'm not exactly an expert in Flash or AS3.

Comment: add an if statement with the condition in my answer at the beginning of the rectangle drawing handler, if false, return from the function without doing the rest of it

Comment: So it would be: if(currentTarget == target){ etc, etc, etc...?

Comment: in principle, yes, but inverting the condition and returning from the function is easier to read, because you don't have to stuff everything of that function into an if block. A matter of preference I guess, your way should work, too. Also, the properties are in the Event object that is passed as parameter, they are not available as local variables.

Comment: I think your way is going to be more preferable. I want to disable the rectangle drawing if anything else is clicked that is not the stage. Also, once the rectangle is drawn, is there a way that it can be manipulated? For example, moved to another part of the stage? I want it drawn on the left side but then moved to the right side later on.

Comment: @dzinermachine I think this is a great new question on how to move your drawn rectangle around.